# Incorrect count

Tags: php, mysql, count

So I have a count for a database and I'm currently struggling.  It tells me there's 1 result no matter how many are there.  I am trying to get the code to count the number of teams with the league set to 5, and there are definitely more than one, but it continuously, the code I have written, returns the number 1.  Here is the code:

```
function inactive_team_search() {
    $count = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `teams` where `league`=5");
    echo count($count);
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!  Probably a silly error where I've been coding for too long but just can't figure it out!

Comment: You are technically echoing the boolean return from the mysql_query. You have to issue other functions such as `echo mysql_num_rows($count);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
function inactive_team_search() 
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT FROM `teams` where `league`=5");
    $count = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $count[0];
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Now go ahead and accept this answer, so no one else will add anymore answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your query instead; this will actually return the count of teams with a league of 5.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `teams` WHERE `league`=5
```

In addition, mysql_query returns its own data structure, which you need to interpret.

```
function inactive_team_search() {
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) inactiveCount FROM `teams` WHERE `league`=5";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(!$result) { 
        echo 'Could not run query.';
    }
    else {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
        echo $row['inactiveCount'];
    }
}
```

Finally, as an aside, mysql_query is deprecated starting in PHP 5.5, so it'd be good for you to switch to using either [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Comment: Ok, I'm tired, so how do I return this as an integer haha?  I have this as $count but I can't remember how exactly it is that I retun the result of it haha?

Answer (score 0):

```
function inactive_team_search() {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `teams` where `league`=5");
    echo mysql_num_rows($result);
}
```